# How to push to protected main branches in a GitHub Action?

Tags: github, github-actions

This is my github action workflow.

```
name: Release

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  release:
    name: Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          persist-credentials: false
      - name: Setup java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11
      - name: Setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: "14.x"
          cache: npm
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: Build package
        run: npm run build --if-present
      - name: Semantic release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
          HUSKY: 0
        run: chmod +x script/prepare-release.sh && npx semantic-release
```

However, my workflow fails with the following error log.

```
[semantic-release] › ✖  An error occurred while running semantic-release: Error: Command failed with exit code 1: git push --tags https://x-access-token:[secure]@github.com/didrlgus/convention-template.git HEAD:main
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/main.        
remote: error: At least 1 approving review is required by reviewers with write access.
```

Maybe it's because my main branch is a protected branch.
How can I push with a protected branch on github action?

Comment: What about the approved review in the error description? Did that happen?

Comment: So you are trying to push to protected branch. You can't do this directly. Instead of this please create a PR, then let someone accept your pr and then you can merge it from the PR. This is the workflow for protected branch. You can't merge your changes directly.

Comment: Approve of the PR has already been made. 
After that, I tried merge for the approved PR.
When attempting merge, the above github action workflow is executed.
However, when the workflow is executed, the above error occurs.

Comment: Both GitHub Actions and GitHub's "protected branches" are GitHub-specific concepts; I switched your [tag:git] to [tag:github] here.

Answer (score 29):

There is a workaround. Steps as follows:

1. Create new Github user eg. `my-org-bot`
2. Generate **Personal Access Token** for this user on https://github.com/settings/tokens and save it somewhere (select repo scope for the token)
3. Go to your repo and add `my-org-bot` to contributors
4. Open your branch protection rules and add `my-org-bot` to the rule below:
   [image]
5. Go to repository secrets and add new secret for Actions with key =`BOT_ACCESS_TOKEN` and the value = **Personal Access Token** generated previously
6. Modify your GH Workflow Checkout step with below:
   [image]

Now your workflow should be able to push directly to your protected branch on behalf of `my-org-bot` user.

Comment: I can't seem to locate the "Allow specified actors to bypass required pull requests"-setting. Is this only available in the Enterprise edition perhaps?

Comment: I don't use enterprise and do have this option. Under Protect matching branches, select Require a pull request before merging. A bunch more checkboxes appear. The last one is Allow specified actors to bypass required pull requests.

Comment: I don't have it either, on enterprise or personal org. I can only bypass branch protection rules by team, not app, using the bypass list in the ruleset. By app would be nice.

Answer (score 11):

Just found that you can use [GitHub deploy keys](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/managing-deploy-keys):

1. Generate SSH key pair: `ssh-keygen -t ed25519`. No need for passphrases etc.
2. Add public key (`.pub` one) as a deploy key at `Your repo -> Settings -> Security -> Deploy keys`, check "Allow write access".
3. Add private key as a secret at `Your repo -> Settings -> Security -> Secrets and variables -> Actions`
4. Specify your secret key when checking out the repo:

   ```
   - name: Checkout
     uses: actions/checkout@v3.5.2
     with:
       ssh-key: ${{secrets.YOUR_SECRET_KEY}}
   ```

Such deployment key is not tied to any account, but gives full write access including bypassing branch protection rules:

> Deploy keys with write access can perform the same actions as an organization member with admin access, or a collaborator on a personal repository.

Comment: When you add the private key as a secret, it's tieing it to your account and bound by its permissions.

Comment: @drone.ah "Deploy keys with write access can perform the same actions as an organization member with admin access, or a collaborator on a personal repository", "it isn't tied to the specific user, but rather to the repository", see https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/managing-deploy-keys#cons-of-deploy-keys

Comment: Thanks @Yaaz. I don't remember making the comment - but looks like I jumped the gun!

Answer (score 3):

The solution that works for us is as follows:

```
name: Version and Package Repo
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master, main ]
jobs:
  build:
    if: github.event.commits[0].author.name != 'GitHubActions'
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
    - name: Checkout repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
        token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
    - name: Configure git
      run: |
        git config user.name "GitHubActions"
        git config user.email "<>"
    - name: Install NPM Packages
      run: npm install
      env:
        NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: $\{{ secrets.PAT }}
    - name: Version and Package
      run: npm version patch --force
      env:
        NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: $\{{ secrets.PAT }}
    - name: Update git
      run: |
        git push
        git push --tags
```

This runs on all pushes to master and main branches (we use the same script on multiple repos) and it:

- checks the repo out
- configures git
- installs and then versions some NPM packages (not relevant to this issue, aside from the job making some kind of change to the repo) - this creates a new commit
- pushes the changes back to the same branch

secrets.PAT is a personal access token of a user with admin rights and the repo has branch protection on, but excludes admins.

It is worth considering that if you run `git push` from an action with the `on push` trigger and you're using a PAT rather than GITHUB_TOKEN, then the action will run in a loop. If you are using GITHUB_TOKEN then GitHub Actions prevents the action running again automatically. We use the conditional `if` line at the top of the job to prevent the job running if the author name of the last commit is `GitHubActions`. This is the author name set in the `Configure git` stage, so the commits that happen within this job (as a result of npm version patch) are from an author with this name.

If the author variable doesn't work for you, there are plenty of others you can use:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context
https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#push

The downside of this approach is that you always get a second run appear in your list of actions which is immediately skipped.

Comment: You can just include [skip actions] in commit message to prevent the action from running again.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting. The commit above is created by `npm version patch`, but we could change it to use `npm version -m <message> patch` to control the message

Answer (score 0):

I couldn’t find a solution that was acceptable to me/work. So, the only option I was left with was avoiding updates in CI that need to be pushed up. That means versioning and changelogs have to be done as part of a user commit/PR. And I created some tooling it make sure it’s done right, in case it helps anyone else: https://github.com/Shakeskeyboarde/anglerci