# Prevent Recursive Workflow Triggering on Merge Push to main Branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to know how to prevent a GitHub Actions workflow from recursively triggering itself.

I have a simple workflow which pulls in the repository and commit a change to `main`, then push to `origin` to `main`.

Since the workflow has a trigger on push to `main`, this causes the workflow to be triggered recursively. The [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#triggering-a-workflow-from-a-workflow) indicates that if the `GITHUB_TOKEN` is set to `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}`, then no recursive calling should occur.

Am I doing this incorrectly?

My workflow:

```
name: Test preventing workflow recursion

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3.5.2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.xxx }}            

      - name: Make changes and commit 
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          echo a >> test.txt
          git config user.name 'bot'
          git config user.email '...'
          git add .
          git commit -m "Update explorationsContent.md" --no-verify
          git push
```

When I run this workflow, I recursively trigger more workflow runs.

Comment: Did you try removing the token informed in the `actions/checkout` to check what happens?

Comment: @GuiFalourd Oh interesting. I removed the "with:  ... token" and when I did this I got an error when trying to push to main: `Waiting on code owner review from [repo user]. Required status check "run" is expected. You're not authorized to push to this branch.` 

What I think this means is that when the token was provided in the first step, it was overriding the use of the secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN. But, the secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN doesn't have the right permissions to push to the main branch with bypassing branch permissions. Does that make sense?

Comment: Just did some more research and [found someone in the same conundrum as me here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69263843/how-to-push-to-protected-main-branches-in-a-github-action). I think I'm pretty much stuck with having a second workflow trigger.

Comment: `Does that make sense?` That was my guess as well. Regarding the new return, does the branch you're pushing to have a protection configured on the repository?

Comment: @GuiFalourd Yep, it has branch protection rules such as requiring a pull request. The token I was originally using has the correct permissions to by pass branch protection.

Comment: In that case, I understand this is the expected behavior. Do you still have any question regarding the behavior or can we add an official answer to the question explaining what happened?

Comment: @GuiFalourd Makes sense now, I'll add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial problem is that I was specifying a token in the `Checkout` step which was overwriting the `GITHUB_TOKEN` so the behavior to prevent recursive workflows was not active.

But, unfortunately, since I have branch protection rules on my repo, I have to use a token for a github user with permissions to bypass branch protections, so I cannot use the `GITHUB_TOKEN`.

The solution is to include some type of "base case" in the workflow which will stop the second workflow that is kicked off recursively from executing.

Comment: It would be great if you could leave a little YAML fragment, associated to the workflow in the question that would show this "base case" so that there is some visualization/"YAMLfication" of the description. Not a requirement, just a suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid getting the "recursively trigger more workflow runs" error by using a PAT (Personal Access Token).

Create your PAT in your GitHub account settings. The PAT must grant repository permissions for 'Contents' and 'Workflows,' and then everything should work well. Here, I have rewritten the code to provide some help:

```yaml
name: Test preventing workflow recursion

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.MY_PAT_WITH_REPO_CONTENTS_AND_WORKFLOWS_PERMISSIONS }}

      - name: Make changes and commit
        run: |
          echo a >> test.txt
          git config user.name 'bot'
          git config user.email '...'
          git add .
          git commit -m "Update explorationsContent.md" --no-verify
          git push
```

Comment: It looks like there is now another escape hatch: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/skipping-workflow-runs. While using a PAT, you can skip the CI workflows by tweaking your commit message.